# ssh on vnc tightvnc server

Tags: vnc

ive got xfce on pi4 b 4gb with ubuntu buster.I installed vnc tight server follwed instructions and comes to tunnel setup right at the end it doesnt wan to says address already in use.
bind [127.0.0.1]:5901: Address already in use
i used :lsof -ti:5901
5161
5535
and these two items appear
then did a kill but now its this
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.149 port 22: Connection refused
is this to connect only or must it be running to be connected to ?

Comment: localhost:5901 in use - so use another port for server and client. Since there is no Ubuntu buster version I doubt your question belongs in this forum---

Answer (score 1):

The "Ubuntu Buster" you refer to is incorrect, the Buster version is a RaspberryPi (Raspian) version.

When VNC Server starts, the default is to bind to port numbers starting at 5901, so it looks like you already had a VNC Server session running on 127.0.0.1:5901 - which would be the default.

It looks like you have the PI setup to launch VNC Server bound to localhost only, this means you won't be able to connect from an external client.

Reboot the PI, launch a terminal, run the following "vncserver localhost no" - this will start VNC server on the next available port (starting at 5901), listening for external clients.

Next, from an external client, run a VNC Client (I use TigerVNC Client) and connect to **hostname:port** where port will probably be 5902 in this instance.

That *should* get you connecting via VNC.

For SSH, launch the RaspberryPI Configuration application (Preferences - RaspberryPI Configuration) and make sure it is turned on.  This will allow SSH connections on port 22.